# Prove that $\zeta = \frac {(2+i)}{(2-i)}$ is not a root of unity of any degree, even though $|\zeta |=1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $\zeta = \frac {(2+i)}{(2-i)}$ is not a root of unity of any degree, even though $|\zeta |=1$.

---

Suppose it is a root of unity of some degree $n\in\mathbb{Z}, n \geq 1$, then (if I'm not wrong) we have $$Im(\zeta ^n) = 0$$ $$ \zeta^n - \zeta ^{n*} = 5^{-n}((3+4i)^n-(3-4i)^n) = 0 , ^*-complexconjugate$$ $$(3+4i)^n=(3-4i)^n$$
If I wanted to prove it's false by induction, would that make a proof? What could be other ways to prove it? I know that $\frac{arg(\zeta)}{\pi} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ (rational numbers), but it seems to be the conclusion of this exercise rather than proof.

Comment: Any root of unity $\in \Bbb{Q}(i)$ must be in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ and since $|a+ib|^2=a^2+b^2$ it is immediate that the only ones are $1,-1,i,-i$.

Comment: Twice you wrote $\;2-1\;$ in the denominator instead of $\;2-i\;$ , which *seems* to be what ypou meant...

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks, edited

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$ \zeta=\frac{2+i}{2-i}=\frac{(2+i)^2}{(2-i)(2+i)}=\frac{3+4i}{5}$$
and so $\zeta$ is a root of the polynomial
$$ X^2-\frac65X+1$$
or equivalently of
$$ 5X^2-6X+5.$$
If $\zeta$ is an $n$th root of unity (with clearly $n>2$), then it must be the case that $5X^2-6X+5\mid X^n-1$. This must hold not only in $\Bbb Q[X]$, but also in $\Bbb Z[X]$, which is absurd.

Comment: "If ζ is an nth root of unity (with clearly n>2), then it must be the case that $
5X^2-6X+5\mid X^n-1$" - Why is that?